# doesn't send the first request with http patch to update in working with firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Just want to update my database after every time pushed the More or Less button (Please take a look at my project ) but the problem is doesn't send the first request and after second request data will send to the firebase and update the special part
react and redux don't have any problem (the base of this project wrote with them) as I asked about it of a redux consultant .
whole the problem come back to involving my app with firebase

Demo :https://zealous-allen-932726.netlify.app/ .

Github : https://github.com/alibidjandy/burger

this is the Api configuration :

```
import { current } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from 
"@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";
import {
  BurgerType,
  OrderType,
} from "../components/Layouts/burger/burgerSlice/burgerSlice";

export const burgerApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "burgerApi",
  tagTypes: ["Ingredients"],
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl:
      "https://burger-order-brown-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app",
  }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getIngredients: builder.query<BurgerType, undefined>({
      query: () => {
        return { url: "/burger.json", method: "GET" };
      },
      providesTags: ["Ingredients"],
    }),
    editIngredients: builder.mutation({
      query: ({ burger, ing, value, resetToZero }) => {
        return {
          url: `/.json`,
          method: "PATCH",
          body: { burger },
        };
      },
      async onQueryStarted(
        { ing, value, resetToZero },
        { dispatch, queryFulfilled }
      ) {
        const patchResult = dispatch(
          burgerApi.util.updateQueryData(
            "getIngredients",
            undefined,
            (draft) => {
              if (resetToZero) {
                const ingredients = draft.ingredients;
                ingredients.map((ing) => {
                  if (ing.Qty) {
                    ing.Qty = 0;
                  }
                  return ing;
                });
                draft.totalCost = 0;
              } else {
                const ingredient = draft.ingredients[ing.id]!;
                draft.totalCost -= ingredient.Qty! * ingredient.cost!;
                ingredient.Qty! += value;
                draft.totalCost += ingredient.Qty! * ingredient.cost!;
                draft.totalCost.toFixed(2);
                if (draft.totalCost < 0) {
                  draft.totalCost = 0;
                }
              }
            }
          )
        );
        try {
          await queryFulfilled;
        } catch {
          patchResult.undo();
        }
      },
    }),
    setOrders: builder.mutation({
      query: ({ name, email, postalCode, street, burger }) => {
        return {
          url: "/orders/.json",
          method: "POST",
          body: { name, email, postalCode, street, burger },
        };
      },
    }),
    getOrders: builder.query<OrderType[], undefined>({
      query: () => {
        return { url: "/orders.json", method: "GET" };
      },
      providesTags: ["Ingredients"],
    }),
  }),
});
export const { editIngredients, getIngredients } = burgerApi.endpoints;
export const {
  useGetIngredientsQuery,
  useEditIngredientsMutation,
  useGetOrdersQuery,
  useSetOrdersMutation,
} = burgerApi;
```

Comment: Please identify the sections of code relevant to the question and post them **inline** here in the question using the [code formatting tools available](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). While your links may work right now, when someone comes along in 6 months with the same issue, the links are unlikely to contain the same information. You are also likely to get a faster response the more you place a magnifying glass over a particular section of code.

Comment: I understand , as my project doesn't those little one I was preferred to linked the question from here to the Github and Netlify which is appropriate for this kind of questions but your advice is absolutely right